# Background image not resizing when switching from portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, css, web-applications, cordova

I have the following CSS:

```
    @media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    body {
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    background-size: auto 100%;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    body {
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    }
    }
```

That works fine on every device except iPhone with iOS 6.3 and smaller (works fine with iOS 7)

On iOS 6 while switching from portrait to landscape, the landscape screen is only covered half way by the background img, any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the bug.
In the "meta" tag if you specify the "height" property, the view will NOT cover the whole width in Landscape mode.

Bad Code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=auto, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Good Code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```